# Structuring Django URL Patterns

Tags: django, url-pattern

I'm new to Django, and I'm having trouble understanding URL patterns. When a user visits the index page of my website (http://www.example.com), they have the ability to conduct a search. They input a first name in one box, and a last name in another, and then click a search button. The user's search returns information on a results page (http://www.example.com/results). Everything works perfectly when I use the following pattern:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
url(r'^results',views.results, name='results'),
...
)
```

However, instead of a rending a '/results' URL for every single search, how would I render a URL like this that captures the actual query:

```
http://www.example.com/results/<first_name>'+'<last_name>/
```

'first_name' and 'last_name' are request.session[] variables stored in the view. I'm sure that this is a very simple problem, but given that I'm new to all of this I was hoping someone could help me understand how this works.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Normally search parameters are passed through a query string: `http://www.example.com/results/?first_name=john&last_name=doe` and then you can access them in your view using `request.GET`. So no need to specify another url.

Comment: Sure, that works. So, there is nothing special that I can do to show the full path of the url instead of just '/results'? I suppose it's not a huge issue but visually is nice.

Comment: If first_name and last_name are always supplied, you can use them as url parameters url(r'^results/(?P<first_name>\w+/(?P<last_name>\w+))',views.results, name='results'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By naming groups in your url pattern. Of course, this is complicated if you just concatenate first_name and last_name because then you can't know how to distinguish which is anyone. You should concatenate like this `first_name+"/"+last_name` and then your url pattern should look like this:

```
url(r'^results/(?P<first_name>[\w-]+)/(?P<last_name>[\w-]+)$',views.results, name='results'),
```

Then, your results view, should accept two parameters:

`def results(request, first_name, last_name):`

Hope you are familiar with regexp. And, ofc you need to control yourself if first_name and last_name are not correct (i.e. void, odd values, etc.).

Comment: I get an error saying I'm requesting 'http://www.example.com/results' and no url patterns match. In this solution, do I need to adjust my HttpResponse to request the same regex? Currently, my template is at 'results.html', which is what I'm requesting in my HttpResponse.

Comment: this because you don't have to request this url. You have to request example.com/results/first_name/last_name. This request will call your view and your view will pass the data to your template to render it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your suggestions! Regex is extremely powerful; I'll need to spend a couple of weeks learning it more closely. Using your suggestions, I was able to get it to work using the following:

urls.py

```
url(r'^results/(?P<first_name>\w)+(?P<last_name>\w)',views.results, name='results')
...
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
...
return HttpResponseRedirect('results/' + first_name + '+' + last_name)

def results(request,first_name,last_name):
...
```

Thanks again!